# laravel5: does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, foreach, get

I have an error

> does not exist on this collection instance.

In my show .blade.php, I want to show ten featured posts.

So in my controller, I used to `get()` method. And in my view page, I used `@foreach`. But it doesn't work.

Instead of `get()`, I used `first()`. Then It worked.
I could show only the latest post.

But it is not what I want to accomplish.
Because

> I want to show the ten latest posts.

ResultsController.php

```
public function show($id,Post $post)
{
    $particular_post= Post::find($id);
    $featured_posts = Post::latest()->limit(10)->get();

    $posts['particular_post'] = $particular_post;
    $posts['featured_posts'] = $featured_posts;

    return view('posts.show',compact('posts'));
}
```

show.blade.php

```
 @foreach($posts['featured_posts'] as $featured_post)
        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

            <div class="swiper-slide">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$posts['featured_posts']->image) }}" alt="" width="300px" height="200px">
                </div>
                <div class="card-information">
                        <div class="event-name">
                            {{ $posts['featured_posts']->title }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="heart">
                            <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: #F70661"></i>
                        </div>
                    <div class="event-date">
                        {{ $posts['featured_posts']->date }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-info">
                        <p>{{ str_limit($posts['featured_posts']->description, 10) }}
                            <a href="#" style="color: white">...see more</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
            @endforeach
```

web.php

```
Route::get('results/{id}', 'ResultsController@show')->name('posts.show');
```

Comment: Still the same posts are showing up. I am using swiper.js, and the layout is coming to be messy.

Comment: $posts['featured_posts']->title, this wouldn't work. title doesn't exists here you have to get it from $featured_post just like @Devsi pointed put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its multiple item then your blad template should like

and access variable as `$featured_post->variable`

```
@foreach($posts['featured_posts'] as $featured_post)
    <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$featured_post->image) }}" alt="" width="300px" height="200px">
            </div>
            <div class="card-information">
                    <div class="event-name">
                        {{ $featured_post->title }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="heart">
                        <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: #F70661"></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="event-date">
                    {{ $featured_post->date }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-info">
                    <p>{{ str_limit($featured_post->description, 10) }}
                        <a href="#" style="color: white">...see more</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Still the same posts are showing up. I am using swiper.js, and the layout is coming to be messy.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `take()` instead of `limit()`

```
Post::latest()->take(5)->get();
```

Or

```
Post::orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(5)->get();
```

Or change the code of blade file.

```
@foreach($posts['featured_posts'] as $featured_post)
    <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$featured_post->image) }}" alt="" width="300px" height="200px">
            </div>
            <div class="card-information">
                    <div class="event-name">
                        {{ $featured_post->title }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="heart">
                        <i class="fas fa-heart fa-lg" style="color: #F70661"></i>
                    </div>
                <div class="event-date">
                    {{ $featured_post->date }}
                </div>
                <div class="card-info">
                    <p>{{ str_limit($featured_post->description, 10) }}
                        <a href="#" style="color: white">...see more</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
        @endforeach
```